# many divs side by side vertical alignment

Tags: css, html

I hope you will understand me. There is a wrapper with width of 360px, it allows only 3 columns of divs. I just want to be able to drop in another div anytime I want and then all previous will be moved along. I have a problem, it seems like divs go to next row but they align verticaly to the tallest one from previous row. Please have a look at the example below (I had to use a picture as the code wasn't showing right). The last green one should be touching the tall red one from above. I am not looking for static positioning it has to be automatic so when I change wrappers width to larger more divs will automatically be included in the rows.

[image]

Below is the image of a wrong result.

[image]

Comment: Could you post the image of your expected result?

Comment: In order to make this work properly, you can't position your `div` elements using `position:relative; or position:static; float:left` If the elements are being added dynamically, and you want them to fit snuggly together, you'll probably have to either use something like http://masonry.desandro.com/ or write some custom JS.

Comment: c--misura: masonry script is beautiful! thank you very much this is exactly what I wanted, a bit shame that css can't do it but JS is doing it very nicely! Thanks again

Comment: please close this question or answer it yourself for it to be considered answered

Answer (score 0):

Masonry script is the closest as I can get to what I need, shame it is JS...